# MYSQL DATABASE create procedure

Tags: mysql

have a question for you guys,

trying to make a procedure for my mysql table but I need some assistance ...

IM completely block ...

I need to create a procedure that will show the parents name in my table but the table show parents id

ex.

```
(DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE fetch_animal_parents (IN animal_id INT, OUT animal_name VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
DECLARE animal_mom INT DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE animal_dad INT DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE animal_name_mom VARCHAR(10) ;
DECLARE animal_name_dad VARCHAR(10) ;
SELECT name INTO animal_name, (SELECT name  FROM animal WHERE id = child.mother_id)  INTO animal_name_mom,
 (SELECT name FROM animal WHERE id = child.father_id)  INTO animal_name_dad
FROM animal AS child ;
END //)
```

What im doing wrong ....

................................................................................................

Any input ...

Comment: I think you should simply use two joins. Hint: Write your query as a SELECT statement first until you get the result you want. Then rewrite this query as stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

1) why do you select mom/dad's name when you are not using them anywhere?

2) I imagine your procedure should take an child animal id as input and give mom & dad's name as output(that's what you procedure name suggest). In that case you need to either have 2 output value or you need to concatenate those names into 1 variable and return them.

3) @VMai suggested a 2 join format which I would agree. The query will be something like..

```
SELECT mom.name,dad.name INTO animal_name_mom, animal_name_dad
FROM (select mother_id,father_id from animal where id = <precedure_input>) AS `child`
INNER JOIN (select id,name from animal) AS `mom` ON (mom.id=child.mother_id)
INNER JOIN (select id,name from animal) AS `dad` ON (dad.id=child.father_id)
```

I see that you have as least tried something on your own (thou very confused). I'd suggest you to start with learning some basic syntax/keyword/functions of mysql before trying procedures. Learn to use `GROUP BY`, variations of `JOIN` and you could handle a lot of basic querys.